# Rxjs filter and map not return anything

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, rxjs

I am trying to Get info from firebase and filter it using Rxjs 6.

I have a few questions about that:

1. I Read object by uid and get the information. in this object I have favorite and I trying to filter from the favorite just a specific uid. but I think because its array of object I cant filter so I load separately just the favorite from firebase.
2. when I using pipe and filter i get an error in ts. the problem is: Property 'uid' does not exist on type 'any[]' .
   I can compile just if I use  // @ts-ignore. anyway, I don't get from rxjs nothing.
3. when I using map in the filter I get the following problem:  data.favorite.filter is not a function (in the web console).

The DB structure:

```
profile{
 NAg0E9IXrjeKMw3tLxPrlyvcdBr2{
        name:david,
        age:20,
        favorite{
                  NHXL2LD5LIfgdfvr{
                                   name:mike,
                                   uid:gh4Q0OEfNHXL2LD5LIgFpVmdmm92
                                  }
                  Q0OEfNHX2LD5Ldsdv{
                                   name:ron,
                                   uid:Vmdmm92dNHXL2LD5LIgFpEfNHXL2
                                   }
                 }
        }
 gh4Q0OEfNHXL2LD5LIgFpVmdmm92{
        name:mike,
        age:26,
        favorite{
                  rlyvcdBr25LdsIXrdv{
                                   name:david,
                                   uid:NAg0E9IXrjeKMw3tLxPrlyvcdBr2
                                   }
                 }
        }
}
```

the service code:

```
  getDataObj(objpath:string){
    this.objRef = this.db.object(objpath);
    this.obj = this.objRef.valueChanges();
    return this.obj;
   } 

   getDataList(listpath:string){
    this.itemsRef = this.db.list(listpath);
    this.items = this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes => 
        changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
      )
    );
  return this.items;
```

the component code:

```
//Here I get Problem 3
   this.db.getDataObj("/Profile/" + this.uid).pipe(
map(data => data.favorite.filter((res) => res.uid===this.uid))).subscribe(res=>console.log(res));

//Here I get Problem 2
      this.db.getDataList("/Profile/" + this.userAuth.uid + "/favorite").pipe(filter(data => data.uid == this.uid)).subscribe(res => {                                  
          console.log(res)});
```

if I do filter like that it works for me:

```
      this.db.getDataList("/Profile/" + this.userAuth.uid + "/favorite").subscribe(res => {                                  
          console.log(res.filter(names =>names.uid == this.uid));
          console.log(res)});
```

thank you

Comment: Since you're using typescript, you can try actually declaring the types on your objects. What types do you expect at each step in your streams?

Comment: Your `data` in an array, it doesn't have `.uid`. You should use `map` instead of `filter` and use `filter` inside the `map`.

Comment: anyway, I get the problem data.uid is not function in the map